# Mouse click when the application is busy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

When I click on anywhere on my application when the application is busy it changes the cursor into a generic wait cursor.  Is there anyway I can code it for an animated cursor?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you must be doing some heavy operation on main UI thread. Do your processing in background (in separate thread).

You may use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) or [Thread](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) class to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will always use the generic "busy" cursor if the user tries to interact with it and your application is not responding.

The solution to this is to *not do processing on the UI thread* - do it on other threads, so your UI remains responsive.

If your UI is still responding, you can set a custom cursor to indicate that your application is busy processing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the windows application in ASP.NET then there is a option realted to cursor in properties of the form(nit clearlly remember, it was like wait.cursor). You can use that to display the custom cursor at the time of processing also.